# Allure report from CircleCI artifact files shows `Allure Report unknown`

Tags: python, pytest, circleci, allure

I can generate and serve Allure reports on the local machine with:

```
pytest --alluredir=allure_report
allure serve allure_report
```

I try to generate an Allure report on CircleCI. I attach the directory with Allure report files as artifacts. When I click on `index.html` it opens an empty report. How can I get the report on CircleCI similar to `allure serve allure_report` command on a local machine?

[Allure artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj2q1.png)

[Empty report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqze6.png)

Comment: Did you ever have any success?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an Orb, such as ayte/allure@0.1.3 or ryanisnan/allure@0.1.2, they both take care of storing your report in the Artifacts folder. Otherwise, you can specify it by using something like this:
- store_artifacts:
path: /home/circleci/project/allure-report

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).